# Why my data get duplicated with nextjs and @apollo/client server side data fetching?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I am building a project using nextjs and @apollo/client. Here I am only fetching my data. My api is provider from other source.

Here I am facing one problem. When I change my page and again go to previous page I can I see data get twice or duplicate. How can I solve my problem.

I follow this repo for setup- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo

[image]

Here is my code-

`apolloClient.ts`-

```
import { useMemo } from "react"
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, from, NormalizedCacheObject } from "@apollo/client"
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error"
import { concatPagination } from "@apollo/client/utilities"
import merge from "deepmerge"
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual"

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = "__APOLLO_STATE__"

let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
            console.log(
                `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
            )
        )
    if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`)
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:3001/ecampus",
    credentials: "include"
})

function createApolloClient() {
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
            typePolicies: {
                Query: {
                    fields: {
                        allPosts: concatPagination(),
                    },
                },
            },
        }),
        defaultOptions: {
            mutate: {
                errorPolicy: "all"
            }
        }
    })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()
    if (initialState) {
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()
        const data = merge(existingCache, initialState, {
            arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
                ...sourceArray,
                ...destinationArray.filter((d) =>
                    sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))
                ),
            ],
        })
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data)
    }
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

    return _apolloClient
}

export function addApolloState(client: any, pageProps: any) {
    if (pageProps?.props) {
        pageProps.props[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME] = client.cache.extract()
    }

    return pageProps
}

export function useApollo(pageProps: any) {
    const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME]
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state])
    return store
}
```

And in `_app.tsx`-

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <main className={`${inter.variable} font-sans`}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

And then I one page named `section.tsx`-

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo()
    await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_SECTION_LIST,
        variables: { searchInput: {} },
        context: {
            headers: {
                cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie,
                "user-agent": ctx.req.headers["user-agent"],
                "x-forwarded-for": ctx.req.socket.remoteAddress
            }
        }
    })
    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {},
    })
}
```

After fetching data from `getServerSideProps`, I use data in one component name is `list.tsx`. `list.tsx` called in `section.tsx` page-

```
const { data, error } = useQuery<GetSectionListData>(GET_SECTION_LIST, { variables: { searchInput: {} } });
```

I use this data in a table that you can see on the gif.

Here is my packages-

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.9"
"deepmerge": "^4.3.0"
"lodash": "^4.17.21"
"graphql": "^16.6.0",
```

How can I solve my problem? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

In a very similiar configuration where data fetched server-side was duplicated, I solved it by tweaking the merge function used in cache/type-policies to remove duplicate cache references or by tweaking the merge logic from the `initializeApollo` function.